# I Pad and MS SQL data base

Tags: ipad

I want to devolep a iPad Plugin for an application which is currently working as a web application. My web application now uses MS SQL server as back end, i designed my application as to fetch & update data in my back end MS SQl server, how can i connet my iPad application and  MS SQL data base

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need the native capabilities of the iPad, like going offline, photo library, GPS etc, then you can make your website to display correctly on the iPad browser (Safari).  This way it can work across iPad, iPhone, Droid, other mobile devices.

If you do need a native iPad app, then you need to expose your CRUD operations with some type of service (usually RESTful, asmx will work as well) that your app can access.  You don't want to directly connect your app to your SQL database.

In essence create the API that your app can work against, then build your app to run against this API.  I built an iPad app that connects to an ASP.NET system that did just this that connected to the ASMX web services to fetch and update the database.